# Problema com funções sendo executadas várias vezes

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber como sanar esse problema. Exemplo:

Tenho uma função de `fadeIn/fadeOut`. O evento que dispara a função é o `OnClick` em algum elemento. A questão é que: Como evitar que quando eu der dois cliques ou mais, a função seja executada todas as vezes que eu clicar, uma instância por cima da outra?

Dessa forma, a função executa de novo e *buga* todo o efeito. Gostaria de saber como "parar" a estância da função que já está executando, e só aí executar ela novamente, ao perceber um novo clique antes de que ela se complete...

Tem algo a ver com aquele `function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }` ?

Não sei se expliquei bem, mas, quem entender e puder ajudar eu fico muito grato. Até mais.

Comment: Como está seu código?

Comment: Crie um exemplo demonstrando este problema, da uma lida neste artigo para te auxiliar nisto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Vamos lá, entenda que precisamos ver seu código para te ajudar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Com um código poderia responder melhor, mas basicamente o que precisa fazer é ter uma variável global que controle se já foi executado ou não, algo assim:

```
var fadeJaExecutado = false;
```

na função que vai executar o efeito:

```
if (!fadeJaExecutado) {
    //faz o que tem que fazer
    fadeJaExecutado = true;
}
```

Agora se o que deseja é que ele não execute mais de uma vez simultaneamente aí a solução é outra, seria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
var fadeExecutando = false;

function fade() {
    if (!fadeExecutando) {
        fadeIn();
        fadeExecutando = true;
    } else {
        fadeOut();
        fadeExecutando = false;
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/DOM/Fade.js).

Pode ser que parte da lógica do `fadeIn()`/`fadeOut()` talvez seja melhor trazer pro `fade()`, como o `setTimeout()`. Mas seria melhor ver o código que está fazendo primeiro. Eu melhoro se a pergunta melhorar.

Answer (score 3):

você pode adicionar uma classe ao elemento no click, e verificar se essa classe existe

```
 $('#test-btn').on('click', function(){
        if(!$('#test').hasClass('fadding')){
        $('#test').addClass('fadding').fadeToggle('fast', function(){
        $(this).removeClass('fadding');
      });
    }
  });
```

criei um [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dihgg/hmyspq5a/1/) com o exemplo

Answer (score 1):

`ev.preventDefault()` vai prevenir o behavior default do element, e.g; `ev.preventDefault()` em um click event de um `<a>` vai impedir que o link do `href=''` seja chamado.

Se estiver usando jQuery, voce pode usar a propriedade `:animated` para verificar se o elemento esta sendo animado, e.g:

`if (!$('.my-element').is(':animated')) { $('.my-element').fadeToggle(); }`

Pelo que entendi do seu problema, seria algo assim sua solução:

```
$('.my-button').click(function (ev) {
  ev.preventDefault(); // ignore the href='#'

  var $fadeElement = $('.my-fade-element');

  if (!$fadeElement.is(':animated')) {
      $fadeElement.fadeToggle();
  }
});
```

- http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/

Answer (score -1):

Amigo, procure saber sobre os padrões Throttle e Debounce acredito que o artigo abaixo vai ajudar.

[Throttle e Debounce](http://loopinfinito.com.br/2013/09/24/throttle-e-debounce-patterns-em-javascript/)

Comment: Esse link pode ser uma boa sugestão, mas sua resposta não terá validade se um dia o link deixar de funcionar. Além disso, é importante para a comunidade ter conteúdo aqui no site mesmo. Seria melhor incluir mais detalhes na sua resposta. Um resumo do conteúdo do link já ajudaria bastante! Saiba mais sobre o assunto neste item do nosso FAQ da Comunidade: [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42/74)